# How to query a data with aggregates plus where?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I need some beginner's help, Find the card number and date of the borrower’s earliest loan for all borrowers who had a loan
before the 3rd January, 2004 or who borrowed a book published before 1920?
My code is this:

```
        select l.cardno, MIN(l.dateout)
        from loan l
        where l.isbn in (select b.isbn from book b
        where b.yearpublished < '1920')
        having MIN(l.dateout) <= '03-JAN-04'
        group by l.cardno
        order by l.cardno asc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question and one that is a bit tricky.  Your approach has the two conditions, but both conditions must be met, and the question asks for `or`.  This leaves you with two choices:  find a way to get both conditions into the same clause (`where` or `having`) or using a union query.

To get both conditions in the same clause, think about the second condition as "let me count up the number of books published before 1920 and keep anyone where that count is greater than 1".  This is a condition you can move to the `having` clause.

The rest of the logic is simply replacing the `in` with a `join`.  The following query assumes that all loans have a valid `isbn` in the book table (otherwise use a `left join`):

```
select l.cardno, MIN(l.dateout)
from loan l left join
     book b
     on l.isbn = b.isbn
having MIN(l.dateout) <= date '2004-01-01' or
       sum(case when b.yearpublished < 1920 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
group by l.cardno
order by l.cardno asc;
```

Note that I replaced the Oracle formatted date constant with the `date` construct.  This allows you to use ISO standard date formats.

Comment: This wa really helpul, but I returned 53 records, I need to return 83 records in total, it seems that the 1920 part wasn't working. This was really helpul!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution! Thanks to the one who gave me the idea, I just changed something and hurray it worked!

```
select l.cardno, MIN(l.dateout)
from loan l left join
 book b
 on l.isbn = b.isbn
having MIN(l.dateout) < date '2004-01-03' or
   sum(case when b.yearpublished <= 1920 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
group by l.cardno
order by l.cardno asc;
```